# Spring Integration, MQTT Support, get Broker answer after calling MessageChannel send

Tags: spring-integration, mqtt

MessageChannel send method only returns a boolean indicating if the message has been send or not

```
boolean send(Message<?> message)
```

Can one implement a way to get the Broker answer either a PUBACK (QoS 1) or PUBREC, PUBCOMP (QoS 2) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just added the ability to get [delivery confirmation events](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/commit/dcdaafc0755bfadf1fb839bb890e98e6e6ad48c7).

Comment: For using a non-released Spring in Gradle:


    `url "http://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot/"

    compile 'org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-mqtt:4.1.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT'`